# How to transform direction from local to world space in three.js

Tags: vector, three.js

You can transform a local position vector to world space using myObject.localToWorld(vector) and back to local with myObject.worldToLocal(vector)

Is there a similar convenient way to transform direction vectors between world and local space?

in Unity this would be myObject.TransformDirection and myObject.InverseTransformDirection

Comment: i don't know enough about unity, so I am going to make the assumption direction is rotation? Where Object3d.rotation is local, you can get world rotation from: https://threejs.org/docs/api/core/Object3D.html#getWorldRotation  But then this is a method of Object3d, and I don't know if you're looking to translate arbitrary nested rotations to world space which may or may not have an object associated with it ...or if this is even what you're trying to translate.

Comment: Similar to rotation just in directional vector form instead of euler or quaternions. Direction is kind of like your heading in vector form. This object is facing "north" (lets call it 0,0,1) in its local space but its parent is facing "east" (1,0,0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can transform a `Vector3`, representing a direction vector, from an object's local space to world space like so:

```
vector.transformDirection( object.matrixWorld );
```

Friendly tip: direction vectors in three.js are assumed to be normalized; that is, have length equal to 1. It is a good idea to adhere to that convention.

three.js r.82